# Modify smb.conf from PHP?

Tags: php, unix, samba, smb

I need to add/remove SAMBA shares through PHP or via SSH (ssh link from PHP).

So far the only solution I've found is a class for primitively handling the file, which I haven't got very much faith in in terms of reliability. (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1546-PHP-Parse-and-recreate-the-Samba-smb-conf-file.html)

Could you recommend a way to do it?

Comment: It's a good idea not to use that specific class. But then the `smb.conf` is a regular ini file regarding the [share] sections. You'll just have to find a more robust parser/rewriter for ini files (which doesn't strip comments). And incidentally that's exactly how the graphical samba configuration tools operate. (Only found a workable one in Python, which is no use to you.)

Comment: I could use SSH from PHP to execute python scripts, if only they were command-line based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find something useful, so I would recommend a likewise simplistic approach. Instead of finding a full-fledged INI parser, it's advisable to work in append-mostly mode. A simple regex would be sufficient to replace existing [share] sections without harming the rest of the smb.conf file.

And you can use the `testparm` utility to probe for correctness before overwriting the real file.

```
define("SMB_CONF", "/etc/samba/smb.conf");

function add_share($section, $options) {

    // read old data
    #$old = parse_ini_file(SMB_CONF);
    $conf = file_get_contents(SMB_CONF);

    // merge new settings
    #if (isset($old[$section])) {
    #    $options = array_merge($old[$section], $options);
    #}

    // remove old share section, if it exists
    preg_replace("/^\[$section\]\s*\n(^(?!\[).*\n)+/m", "", $conf);

    // write out new ini file
    $conf .= "\n\n[$section]\n";
    foreach ($options as $key=>$value) {
        $conf .= "$key = $value\n";
    }
    $tmp = tempnam("/tmp/", "SMB");
    file_put_contents($tmp, $conf);

    // copy if it is syntactically correct
    if (strstr(`testparm -s $tmp 2>&1`, "OK")) {
        rename($tmp, SMB_CONF);
    }
}
```

**Updated** Okay, `parse_ini_file` does not work in either case. It trips over the smb.conf style. So you can only completely replace existing entries, not update them.

Comment: That looks great, will try it out in about an hour. I can use a similar technique to remove shares, or at least remove the allowed users associated with a share.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework's `Zend_Config` setup might be useful as it's able to read/write ini files.

[Zend_Config_Writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html)

Comment: It's not suitable for real configuration files, because it's a simplistic implementation which strips out comments. It's likely to fail on `smb.conf` which has multi-line directives that parse_ini_file isn't prepared for.

Comment: I guess that could be an issue if comments are required in the file or whether multi-line directives are. Let's wait and hear back from the poster!

Comment: True, simplistic approach to the file reading won't work. The comments are trivial, I'm more concerned that some directives are cut or lost and the whole thing blows up. Zend_Config seems alluring, I'll try it out shortly.

Comment: --- Zend_Config_Writer won't work for this particular case - our system is build on Kohana.